# Where to put my code - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code running on my sheet. This code contains two subroutines. But I want to run this code in all my sheets and I was wondering what would be the best approach.

The total code that is running is the following:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(500, 7))
Dim Intersection
Set Intersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Rng)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B2]) Is Nothing Then _
        Range("E:E").Find(vbNullString, [E3], , , , xlNext).Select
End If

If Not Intersection Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Selection.Value) And Selection.Value <> "" Then
        If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRButton)) Then 'right mouse button
            Selection.Value = (Selection.Value + 1)
            Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Select
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(500, 7))
    Dim Intersection
    Set Intersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Rng)

    If Not Intersection Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If anyone could give me tips, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: As currently stated it is difficult to tell what your exact problem is. Right now the answers will probably be too broad, and may raise errors that could easily be avoided if we can *see* the code you're using.  To get more specific answer, please consider revising your question to include the actual subroutines code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in module. You can follow below link.

http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated that just putting your code in another location. If you put your code in a module (which is the right move) you will need to *tell* it to run on other sheets too. You're code can be written to apply to any sheet in any open or closed workbook from a Worksheet objects code module, too. It is all about how it is written.

Are you using works like `Me` or `ActiveSheet` in your code? This is red flag that no matter where you place it the result will probably not be what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I do not use 'Me' or 'ActiveSheet'. And if I put it in a module. Do I need to add code, so that it runs automatically and in every sheet. Or do I need to call that module on each sheet?(also do not know how to do ^ this)

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. When does the code need to run? You can loop through all sheets and execute your code for every sheet. If your code needs to run off some event (like worksheet_change) then you'll need to call the code in your module from your sheet because a module can't see events. Post some code so we can have a better idea of what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a change event to be effective for all the sheets in a workbook, put the code in the ThisWorkbook module and use the Workbook_SheetChange event. This event will fire when any cell is changed in any sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```